# problem with window.location.protocol mock (jasmine, karma)

Tags: javascript, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

In js code, in the method i am testing, i use `window.location.protcol` to specify one of the values.
I can't set it in spec because I get messages like: Cannot redefine property: location

I have tried this and many others:

`spyOn(window.location, 'protocol').and.returnValue('https:');`

or:

`spyOn(window, 'location').and.returnValue({protocol: 'https:'});`

or `spyOnProperty...`

none of the examples from google work.
Any idea?

Comment: How did you try setting `window.location.protocol` when you got the "Cannot redefine property" error?

Comment: If the error was that you can't redefine `location`, it sounds like you did something like `window.location = { protocol: 'https:' }`. Did you try just `window.location.protocol = 'https:'`? That works for me in the browser console, seems like it should work in a test as well

Comment: @awarrier99 yes, none of these assignments worked

Comment: I just added an edit to my existing answer for a different approach that might work for you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** My previous answer is not very ideal - I just thought of another potential solution that may work for your case, which is something I've done before for other globals. Create a new file to host a mock, and in that file use `Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', { writable: true, value: /* your mock here */ })`. Then, leverage the `setupFilesAfterEnv` property of the Jest configuration to tell Jest to run this mock file before running your test suites. You can read more about this configuration property [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array), but the gist is that you need to pass an array containing the file path of your mock. However, a potential downside of this is that this is a global mock that will apply to *all* of your test cases, and the value cannot be changed across these.

Previous answer: This isn't directly a solution, but wherever you're accessing `window.location.protocol`, you could instead wrap that in a function and call the function in your code. Then, in your test you can mock the function call